# What are the commands for for fine-grained control for file permissions? (other than the usual read-write-execute[rwx])

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions, files, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5. I want to implement some permissions using Terminal.
The usual file permissions are: `read` (r), `write` (w), `execute` (x) . What are the other permissions available? How to set them using terminal?

[p.s: I mean more advanced permissions]

Update: by "Advanced permissions" I mean:

> for example- a user can read, write and access a folder and it's files but cannot delete anything.
>
> Example 2: For accessing and creating directions, the capital `X` isused instead of "x" . (tell me if I am wrong)
>
> Example 3: a user group/ user is the owner of a folder and it's files
> but the owner have only read permission. Anther user (Not the owner)
> have full permission (rwx) .
>
> Example 4: a user has read-only permission on folder, but he has full
> permission (rwx) on the subfolders and files.

And like these

Comment: please elaborate what you mean by advanced permissions

Comment: i gave an update in the question body

Comment: You can create and use groups for fine-grained control (create 'users' that are only used as groups). Let the group own a file and let the regular owners belong to groups in order to get the desired permissions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, write and delete permissions follow each other. But remember that in linux file systems (for example `ext4`) permissions are individual for files and directories, so you can have a read-only file in a directory with write access. But if you have write access to the directory, you can delete the read-only file anyway (after a warning).

Comment: Look into ACLs.

Comment: I did not understand this :-- `You can create and use groups for fine-grained control (create 'users' that are only used as groups). Let the group own a file and let the regular owners belong to groups in order to get the desired permissions.`

Comment: `-rwxrw-r--` copied from a directory.  you'll note rwx apply for owner, group & everyone else, so its more than simple rw&x.  your question mentioned only 'owner' permissions; @sudodus highlighted group permissions allow far more fine-tuning (ie. add users to a rwgroup for rw; a rgroup for read only allowing tons of combinations).  for things that are difficult with groups(or beyond) - you have access-control-lists (ACLs as @fkraiem said) & need to learn sticky-bits (represented by the first character in my permission copy '-' means normal file with no ACL)

Comment: If a user can write into a file, they can wipe it out, even if they can't delete it. Deleting files is a Directory permission. Writing into files is a file permission. Therefore anyone who has rx to the directory and rw to the file can zero it out destroying its contents but they can't remove the name.  That okay with your plan?